# Changing a file to another with the same field names

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report built on a file but I want to change the file to another that has the exact same field names, but a different file name. They are both on the same data source.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
Database Lable --> Set Datasource Location--->
```

select current file and target file and click on `update`